# For loop doesn't work in Karel IDE. Can someone explain?

Tags: karel

```
function main(){
   diagonalBeeper();
}

function diagonalBeeper(){
   for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
         move();
         turnLeft();
         putBeeper();
   }
}
```

I want to make a diagonal beeper line in Karel IDE..
So I made this fn which would repeat itself 7 times but it doesn't work.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you keep turning left, you won't go very far. You would need to alternate left, right, left, right

Comment: the for loop doesn't work...

Comment: The [reference](https://stanford.edu/~cpiech/karel/images/reference.png) says it should be `int` instead of `let` (I'm removing the "Javascript" tag from this question, as this is not)